# Unable to Enable Game Center for my App

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, game-center

For some reason I cannot get to this screen to enable Game Center on my app:

[image: Enable Game Center on App]

I never had this issue until Apple changed their site layout.  Simply checking this button:

[image: iTunes Connect Game Center Button]

is not adding Game Center support to my App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Enable Game Center in your App ID. To do this, log into [developer.apple.com](http://www.developer.apple.com) and go to Member Center -> Certificates,Ids & Devices -> App Ids and select your App id. Then make sure Game Center is enabled
2. Make sure Game Center is enabled in Xcode. You can check by going to Project -> Capabilities -> and the check that Game Center is turned on. Once you do that follow to step 3. If it isn't enable it and press fix issues and Xcode should resolve everything by itself.
3. Go to iTunes Connect -> My Apps -> Select your app. Under the upper left corner next to App Store you should see Features. 
   [image: Itunes connect.] 
   Select it, and you'll be taken to this page:
   [image: Game Center Page]
   Press on Game Center and voila, you're ready to set up Leaderboards and Achievements. Congrats. 
   [image: Last Page]

**EDIT:**

What appears to have been the problem was the use of production certificates while development, as the OP pointed out that the PN error got fixed in the released build. Another way to try to fix that type of error is to check if the correct and new provisioning profile is installed.

Hope that helps, Julian!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer Julian.  Unfortunately, my app does not include Leaderboards boards or Achievements, but requires Game Center nevertheless as it makes use of the turn-based gaming API.  I have completed steps one and two, but Game Center is still not enabled (incidentally, I have an older App ID that works just fine .. I was able to enable Game Center without Leaderboards and Achievements before the change to iTunes Connect). Am I being forced to use Leaderboards and Achievements in order to activate Game Center on my App ID?

Comment: No. You're not. I just wanted to outline to you how to activate the app and also how to get both those things to work. However by no means are required to use them. So what you want to use is the turn based gaming API? And what exactly gives you the error that you cannot use it? As if I am not mistaken it now is enabled by default.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am having a difficult time trying to issolate an error message :/  My problem is that Push notifications don't work using my newer App Id (but they work using my older one).

Comment: I thought that your problem was about Game Center, not push notification?

Comment: The Game Center turn-based gaming API makes use of Push Notifications sent by Game Center to alert players that it is their turn.

Comment: Okay. Do you have push notifications enabled on your app is?

Comment: No. Just Game Center. The strange thing is that the testing app ID I set up months ago works just fine (I do not believe I did anything special to set up Game Center notifications).

Comment: Hm. Check, because if I'm not mistaken in the old test is you should have Push enabled. You can do that by following the step of checking the Game Center Id.

Comment: And then click he old ID and check if the button next to push is red, green or yello

Comment: Great idea ... but push notifications disabled on the App Id that works :/

Comment: They are disabled on the id where they work? Hm. Stupid question. Do you have the correct provisioning profiles?

Comment: Sometimes we forget to download the new ones, for the new app ID, what prevents from Push to be received

Comment: So could you check if you have a new provisioning profile specifically for the new app id?

Comment: Yes, I checked that as well! Just can't figure this out! I just went ahead and submitted my app.  Hopefully Game Center notifications work in the live version! :0)

Comment: Okay! Let me know how it goes and what it's called!

Comment: App now in App Store!  It's called Gold Claim!

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gold-claim/id1045285861?ls=1&mt=8